# How to custom the screen GL501000 Release Transactions

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am trying to customize the GL501000 Release Transactions screen but at the time of processing it does not enter my code, it could indicate what is the event that I should use to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

```
    using System;
    using System.Text;
    using PX.Data;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using PX.Objects.BQLConstants;
    using PX.Objects.CS;
    using PX.Objects.CM;
    using PX.SM;
    using System.Linq;
    using PX.Objects;
    using PX.Objects.GL;
    
    namespace PX.Objects.GL
    {
        public class BatchRelease_Extension : PXGraphExtension<BatchRelease>
        {
            public override void Initialize()
            {
                base.Initialize();
    
                PXGraph.InstanceCreated.AddHandler<JournalEntry>((JournalEntry graphGL) =>
                {
                    graphGL.GetExtension<JournalEntry_Extension>().ModifyBatchFrom = true;
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to know that this is being called from a processing screen rather than a one-off user entry.  I'd suggest you might look to the free *T240 Processing Forms* training on the Acumatica OpenUni site.  They show doing this by including a parameter to indicate that this work is originating from a processing form which may simplify your effort and improve performance.  The training example shows:

```
public void AssignOrder(RSSVWorkOrder order, bool isMassProcess = false)
{
    ...
    if (isMassProcess)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you may need to move your event handler addition down into PostGraph instead of JournalEntry.  They both are in the same file in the code repository.  Still, if your goal is to know that it is called from the processing screen, I'd urge you to consider modifying your approach to match the example in T240.

Since it is in a static method, it will be "fun" to rework it, but you want to replace:

```
pg.ReleaseBatchProc(copy);
```

with:

```
pg.ReleaseBatchProc(copy, isMassProcess: true);
```

and add a signature to support:

```
public virtual void ReleaseBatchProc(Batch b, bool unholdBatch = false, bool isMassProcess = false)
```

Next, you will then use the isMassProcess bool value for your special case when mass processing and then call the original signature:

```
public virtual void ReleaseBatchProc(Batch b, bool unholdBatch = false)
```

via:

```
ReleaseBatchProc(b);
```

Example:

```
public virtual void ReleaseBatchProc(Batch b, bool unholdBatch = false, bool isMassProcess = false)
{
    MyMethod(isMassProcess);
    ReleaseBatchProc(b);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, it helped me